# Max() function on node ; python DFS

Tags: python, depth-first-search

in the classic example of DFS below:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

def tree_max_depth(root: Node) -> int:
    def dfs(root):
        # null node adds no depth
        if not root:
            return 0
        # num nodes in longest path of current subtree = max num nodes of its two subtrees + 1 current node
        return max(dfs(root.left), dfs(root.right)) + 1
    print(dfs(root.left))
    return dfs(root) - 1 if root else 0

# this function builds a tree from input; you don't have to modify it
# learn more about how trees are encoded in https://algo.monster/problems/serializing_tree
def build_tree(nodes, f):
    val = next(nodes)
    if val == 'x': return None
    left = build_tree(nodes, f)
    right = build_tree(nodes, f)
    return Node(f(val), left, right)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = build_tree(iter(input().split()), int)
    res = tree_max_depth(root)
    print(res)
```

How is the max function calculating the height in the line below?

```
return max(dfs(root.left), dfs(root.right)) + 1
```

Comment: The max of the heights of the subtrees, plus 1 (just as the comment says).  What part of that do you have trouble with?

Comment: Thx for the resopnse scott -- what is max calculating, i understanding if I were to pass in max(3,4) it would return 4. But what does roof.left represent and how can max determine a value from it, and what is that value?

Comment: It isn't computing `max` of `root.left`; it is computing `max` of  `dfs(root.left)`, which is the height of the tree rooted at `root.left`, which is the left subtree of the tree rooted at `root`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you understand recursion, then you can understand what the block of code does.

Let's say initial node is A. In the begining, `max(dfs(root.left), dfs(root.right)) + 1` is like saying `max(dfs(nodeB), dfs(nodeC)) + 1`.

- First, it calculates `dfs(nodeB)`. This has root.right/left, so it doesn't return 0.
- It continues to `max(dfs(nodeD), dfs(nodeE)) + 1`.
- It goes to NodeD (root.left) which has `None` as root.left/right, so it returns `max(dfs(None), dfs(None))+1)=max(0,0)+1=0+1=1)
- Then, it continues to `dfs(nodeE)` (the root.right). which have root.left/right. So it goes to dfs(nodeF). dfs(nodeF) is root has **NOT** root.left/right so it returns 1 (like nodeD).

So now, we have for the B node, the code `max(1, 2)` where '1' is from root.left (nodeD) and '2' is from nodes E and F. Then chooses the max, which is 2, and then returns 2+1 to the node A.

Node C, has height 1. So, `max(3,1)` is 1. So, max height is 3.

#### An explanation of the `root`

Each time `dfs(root)` is called, then a new root is set. For example, if we call `dfs(nodeB)` (assume nodeB is a node), then the new root is nodeB.

In the block of code:

```py
if not root:
    return 0
```

the if-statement, in reality checks if the root at the moment, is `None`. If we substitute the code above with a root being `None`, it is:

```py
if not None:
    return 0
```

and `not None` as we know results to `true`.

Let's take NodeD. When it's root, it does **NOT** have root.right & root.left (they are `None`). So it is calling `max(dfs(None), dfs(None)+1` which equals to `max(0, 0)+1` because `dfs(None)` returns 0.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the very helpful an comprehensive response, cannot tell you how much i appreciate. questions below:

First, it calculates dfs(nodeB). This is not the root, so it doesnt return 0.
Q:"Where does it indicate in the code to start at nodeB",
It continues to max(dfs(nodeD), dfs(nodeE)) + 1.

It goes to NodeD (root.left) which is root, so it returns 0+1=1.
Q:"I thought 'root' would be NodeA'

Q:"how does NodeA get assigned a value of 1"

Comment: Answer to Q1: It does not indicate to start at nodeB. It starts from nodeA which is the first node. Then it goes `max(dfs(root.left), dfs(root.right)) + 1`. The `root.left` is nodeB and the `root.right` is nodeC, so it begins to calculate `dfs(root.left)` which is the same with `dfs(nodeB)`.

Comment: I've updated my answer about the root. Please ask for further explanation

Answer (score 0):

In the given code, the 'max' function is used to determine the maximum depth (height) of the binary tree at the current node during a depth-first search (DFS) traversal.

Here's a step-by-step explanation of how it works:

1. The function 'tree_max_depth(root: Node) -> int' is the entry point of the program and takes the root of the binary tree as input.
2. The function 'dfs(root)' is a helper function that calculates the depth of the binary tree rooted at the current 'root' node using a recursive depth-first search approach.
3. Inside the 'dfs' function:

> If the 'root' is 'None' (i.e., it represents an empty node), it means there are no nodes in the current subtree, and thus, the depth is 0. The function returns 0 in this case.

> If the 'root' is not 'None', it calculates the depth of the left subtree by calling 'dfs(root.left)' and the depth of the right subtree by calling 'dfs(root.right)'.

> The 'max' function is then used to find the maximum depth among the left and right subtrees. This is because the height of a binary tree is defined as the maximum depth among all its subtrees.

> Adding 1 to the maximum depth of the subtrees accounts for the current node itself, so it includes the depth of the current node in the calculation.

4. The 'tree_max_depth' function calls 'dfs' on the root of the binary tree and returns the result after subtracting 1 from it. The subtraction is performed because the height of an empty tree (i.e., a 'None' node) is conventionally defined as -1.

To summarize, the 'max' function helps find the maximum depth among the left and right subtrees of the current node, and by adding 1 to it, it calculates the depth of the current node's subtree.